# how to remove first two character from string and space

Tags: javascript, html, css

If any body help me out.

i tried two replace first aa and ab with space with this syntax
replace(/^(.){2}/,'').trim() but not work.

like i have tried to remove first aa and ab only print hello word but not work with this syntax
let check = 'aa hello world'
let check = 'ab hello world'

Comment: [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) + [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Just use substring ----   check = check.substring(3); = "hello world"

Comment: Try this : 
check.substr(2, check.length - 1).trim()

Comment: Your replace expression works perfectly fine, I think you simply did not take into account, that replace doesn't _modify_ the original variable, but _returns_ the modified value ...?

Comment: [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) returns a new string, it doesn't convert in-place.

Comment: then just add an IF to see if it start with that and if it does amend the check:   if (check.startsWith('aa') || check.startsWith('ab')) { check = check.substring(3);  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example just adding an IF statement to see if the string starts with aa or ab:

```
 var check = 'aa hello world';

 if (check.startsWith('aa') || check.startsWith('ab')) {
   check = check.substring(3);
 }
```

You can even keep your code:

```
var check = 'aa hello world';

if (check.startsWith('aa') || check.startsWith('ab')) {
  check = check.replace(/^(.){2}/,'').trim()
}

console.log(check)
```

Answer:

```
 "hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

```
let text = "aa hello world!";
if (text.startsWith('aa') || text.startsWith('ab')) {
 text = text.slice(3);
}
```

Result:

```
hello world
```

Comment: Try @Ylama solution